# What is the difference between `assertIn` and `assertContains` in Django?

Tags: python, django, testing

I am studying some Django testing codes and I find `assertIn` and `assertContains` quite similar, I read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/) wherein they didn't say anything about `assertIn` or maybe I couldn't find it.

This example below checks if 'john' appears at the content of `self.email.body`

```
self.assertIn('john', self.email.body)
```

similary this example checks if `csrfmiddlewaretoken` appears at content of `self.response`

```
self.assertContains(self.response, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken')
```

Looks like there syntax is different, but there functionality is the same. Hence, what is the difference?

If you could kindly help me understand this with some basic examples, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**assertIn** is a member of Python's built-in test suite. It is a normal test for membership. For example, you can check the membership of an element of an array. A key in a dictionary etc. You can use it for everything the `in` operator can be used for.

**assertContains** is added by Django in its test suite. It is used specifically for responses. That means you can pass it response object returned by the view. It will evaluate it and check for membership then.

You can read about [assertIn](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIn) and [assertContains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertContains) in the respective documentation.

Comment: Thank you for documentation! it solved even some other issues

Answer (score 8):

Django testing inherits from `unittest` in Python.

`assertContains` is [specific to Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertContains) and allows you to evaluate additional things beyond a simple `assertIn`:

> SimpleTestCase.assertContains(response, text, count=None, status_code=200, msg_prefix='', html=False)[source]
>
> > Asserts that a Response instance produced the given status_code and that text appears in the content of the response. If count is provided, text must occur exactly count times in the response.

While `assertIn` [does simple evaluation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertIn):

> assertIn(first, second, msg=None)
>
> > assertIn(a, b) checks for `a in b`